Is there any mathematically valid statement that defies logic?
I know that in most cases mathematical statements are also logically sound and valid, and vice versa. However, my question is, is there a mathematical statement, expression or theory that does not follow the rules of logics, and thus is "illogical" in a sense? Or is such a situation impossible? I hope to know! I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Banach Tarski Spheres?

Statements, mathematical or any other, cannot be sound and valid, only arguments can be. That aside, to make sense as mathematics, a discourse must include logic as a (proper) part of it and it cannot defy its own logic because that is an oxymoron. It is another matter that this logic can be informal, and/or it can be very different from what we are used to. For example, it can allow some statements to be both true and false and so defy classical logic, see Inconsistent Mathematics.

Any reason for the downvote & close vote? Please tell me where I can improve in order to make this question useful to potential future viewers.

@Conifold Sorry if my terminology isn't correct, if statements can't be called "sound" and "valid", then what's the appropriate terminology for statements?

Statements can be true or false, but that is not a matter of logic. Logic is about deriving statements from other statements, not about their truth or falsity. That is why mathematics has to include some logic. If we cannot derive by logical arguments, at least informally, then we are doing something other than mathematics.

The downvote is not mine, but you could fix "sound and valid statements" and explain your sense of "defying logic" some more.

Please, avoid using terms with two different meanings (that, alas, is the main feature of philosophy...). Illogical seems to be here "contrary to intuition" while "contrary to the rules of logic", especially wrt math, means simply "wrong".

See here for a useful discussion

Perhaps OP is thinking of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel%27s_incompleteness_theorems?
Assuming that a (sufficiently expressive) math theory is consistent , we can prove by a logically sound argument, that particular statements in the theory must be true but are unprovable (by any logically valid proof expressible in the theory). So, those statements must be assumed to be true (if the theory is consistent), but they cannot follow logically from other statements in the theory. This doesn't make them "illogical", but points to a limit of logical "provability" (in relation to "truth").

If we simply arbitrarily define "illogical statements" as "true statements that cannot be derived or proven by a valid proof", then every math theory that includes at least simple arithmetic will have "illogical statements". Axioms (and definitions) could also be considered as "illogical statements" then, since they precede any proofs.

(Just to be fussy: when I wrote "they cannot follow logically from other statements" I meant, of course, "they do not follow logically from other provable statements".)

I'm inclined to say no (math doesn't defy logic) in the following way:
Set's correspond to predicates but not all predicates correspond to sets. Predicates are logical statements.
There is a very close relation between a predicate P(x) and the set {x:P(x)} of all x (in some universe) for which this predicate is true. The basic operations (not, and, or) of logic then correspond to the operations (complement, intersection, union) of set theory.
And Velleman's from How to Prove It:

"We have now introduced seven basic logical symbols: the connectives ∧,
∨, ¬, →, and ↔, and the quantifiers ∀ and ∃. It is a remarkable fact that the
structure of all mathematical statements can be understood using these symbols,
and all mathematical reasoning can be analyzed in terms of the proper use of
these symbols."

Here is a taste of what Velleman is thinking:




So math clearly follows the rules of logic, and then some. But there is a caveat. Math is typically said to not be "reducible" to logic with a large part of that being past failures. But the way forward isn't necessarily cut off. You can read about that here for example.

Not all sets correspond to predicates. The Vitali set is a classic example. Define a relation on the real numbers by x ~ y if x - y is rational. This is an equivalence relation, so it partitions the reals into a collection of equivalence classes. Using the axiom of choice, let V be a set consisting of exactly one member of each equivalence class. V is a set but is not defined by any predicate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set

It is useful to avoid mixing the intuitive philosophical distinction between concepts and their extensions from the mathematical concepts of set. Set theory rigorously defines what sets are in mathematics, but in this way the intuitive expectation that for every concept there is the corresponding collection of those objects satisfying the concept (aka extension) no longer applies.

@user4894 is this because you’re using the AC but not specifying exactly how the choices are made? If so I had a similar  thought while writing my answer: doesn’t using the AC imply there is some predicate even if we can’t (currently?) say exactly how each choice is made? Can we really say not being explicitly definable means there is no predicate? For that matter, why isn’t the construction you’ve made a predicate?

@JKusin I guess if by "predicate" you mean "double secret predicate that's attached to any set by definition," you are right. If it has its standard meaning, you are wrong. But another argument is that there are only countably many predicates (finite-length strings) and uncountably many sets. So most sets are not defined by predicates. Their elements are random. You can't claim every set is defined by a predicate without wildly altering the meaning of predicate. What predicate would you say characterizes the Vitali set?

@user4894 Okay I'll take it I'm wrong on standard (e.g. classical) definitions but there is https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/ for example if we want to migrate away from finite formulas, no? I also shouldn't have to produce the explicit predicate for your set like classical math doesn't have to explicitly construct many objects to say they exist, no? Again, I'm wrong on standard definitions though, and you provide great examples why. But, I haven't seen why we need to be restricted to the standard definitions when there are other accepted logics.

@JKusin Well I'll concede that it's not entirely clear. If X is a set, the predicate x ∈ X exactly characterizes X. I'm not sure how the mathematical philosophers regard this. I'm not even sure how I regard it.

Trivially, for a statement to be mathematically valid we need a definition of validity and the statement must satisfy that definition.
Demonstrating that the statement satisfies the definition is a logical activity. It may not be first order logic, per se, but it will be some deductive system.
Therefore, a mathematically valid statement is logically valid, by definition (under whatever logic is used to define mathematical validity).

Aside: you may be thinking more along the lines of "counterintuitive", in which case the Tarski paradox from the comments is a good example, or the Horn of Gabriel from basic calculus.
You get a lot of strange objects from application of the Axiom of Choice, of which one mystery is their existence but non-constructability: X exists but I can't show it to you....suuuuure ;-)

What are these rules of logic you are referencing?
Most of standard mathematics is embedded inside some kind of First Order Logic.
And so, is all coherent with first order logic.
There are higher order logics, and mathematics that does not follow from a first order logic.
I would say that the closest we could get to a math that defies logic, is to consider meta-mathematics.
However, even meta-mathematics follows it's own kind of logic.
I will be controversal here, and say that any completed infinity defies natural logic ( the logic of the natural world) - as I suspect there are no infinities in our universe.
If we interpret your question this way, then most of mathematics defies "logic"

I (and history) does not agree with your position that all math is reducible to logic. This — logicism/formalism — is a fad of a hundred years. Math—Euclid,Pythagoras as well as logic—Aristotle go back two millennia and they are completely separate areas. But you get a +1 from me for the last paras.  Until Kronecker, Cantorism was regarded as thinly disguised theology.  Kronecker, Brouwer etc.'s objections were not addressed; just steamrolled and ignored

I believe Math is still in it's infancy. Let us see in 10,000 years where mathematics lands. Perhaps, logisticians will eat up all of mathematics. Or maybe, a Mathematicians intuition will always keep them out of the logisticians grasp.

History does disagree, but there is a perspective of unification, where part of progress is identifying where seemingly different areas are the same. My post is, a large Conensus among Modern Mathematicians. Math and Logic seem following a trend of unfiying; the same way eletricity and magnetism were unified. Perhaps, not all of math could ever be brought into the fold. But, ( as if now) an enormous sector of it - the math almost everyone is taught, seems to sit nicely inside logic. But, Mathematical Logic and Set Theory is my most well studied areas of Math. So, be aware of that.
